# Defining a multiplication process for the elements in a set

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

How can I write code that does the following?

Given a set

```
S = {a, a b, a b c} = {A[1], A[2], A[3]}
```

where `A[1] = a`, `A[2] = a b` and `A[3] = a b c`.

I want to form the product from the terms in the set as follows:

$\qquad G = \prod_{i=1}^n 1 - A[i]$

For example:

```
G = (1 - A[1])(1 - A[2])(1 - A[3])

G = (1 - a)(1 - a b)(1 - a b c)

G = 1 - a - a b + a^2 b^2 c + a^2 b c - a^2 b^2 c^2
```

The example is simple enough for me to do the work manually, but when the terms in the set are larger, it would be difficult to carry out this process. How can I get Mathematica to do it for me.

I would like a code solution or suggestions on how to write code to do this.

Comment: Do not use MathJax unnecessarily. I have edited the question to show you how we prefer to see it.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks

Comment: Have you seen [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html)?

Comment: your expansion of G seems incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Expand[Product[1 - i, {i, S}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your notation slightly to get rid of capitals, and I'm starting from an array of `a[i]` instead of your `a`, `b`, `c`. (That means that your `A[i]` are equivalent to my `s[[i]]`). This setup makes things more easily generalizable.

One approach is then

```
n = 3;
r = Array[a, n];
s = Table[Times @@ r[[1 ;; i]], {i, n}];
g = Product[1 - s[[i]], {i, n}]

(* (1 - a[1]) (1 - a[1] a[2]) (1 - a[1] a[2] a[3]) *)
```

which is equivalent to your `(1 - a)(1 - a b)(1 - a b c)` with `a[1] = a`, `a[2] = b`, `a[3] = c`.

If you want this as a function you can apply to numerical vectors, then

```
Clear[n, r, s, g, a]
g[r_] := Block[{n = Length[r], s},
  s = Table[Times @@ r[[1 ;; i]], {i, n}];
  Product[1 - s[[i]], {i, Length[r]}]
  ]

SeedRandom[0]; r = RandomReal[1, 100];
g[r]

(* 0.0840111 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[aa, a, b, c]
Times @@ Array[1 - aa[#] &, 3] /. {aa[1] -> a, aa[2] -> a b,  aa[3] -> a b c}
```

The results is equivalent to your 2nd expression for `G`.  Use `Expand` to get something like your (apparently incorrect) 3rd expression for `G`.

**Edit:** Rereading your question, it seems like you may not even need the array of variable.   If you really have `ss` already, you can just use `Times @@ (1 - ss)` (where I am using `ss` in place of `S`).

Answer (score 1):

```
        Clear[a, b, c, S, v]
    S = {A[1], A[2], A[3]}
     v = {a, a *b , a*b*c}
rules = Rule @@@ Partition[Riffle [S, v], 2]

    Times @@ Map[  1 - #1 &, S] /.  {rules} // Expand
```